# Post method json data and receive in aspx file

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json, ajax

Hello I'm using jQuery AJAX to send a data to my aspx file. Here is my AJAX:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#openmodal').click(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Video.aspx",
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
            data: {
                "videoid": "id"
            },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(resultData) {
                console.log(resultData);
            },
            error: function(errordata) {
                console.log(errordata);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

My aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    string query = Request.QueryString[0];
    if (query != null) {
        if (!IsPostBack) {
            gvShow.DataSource = VideoBL.GetVideo(query);
            gvShow.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

But I keep getting this error:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException
>
> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative
>   and less than the size of the collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.Firstly you need to change the `data` parameter to point to the `id` variable:

```
data: {"videoid": id}
```

2.Secondly, instead of using:

`string query = Request.QueryString[0];`

use

`string query = Request.Form["videoid"];`

3.Unfortunately even after you made the two changes above your data binding logic **will not work**.You cannot set a data source of the `GridView` control by making an AJAX call.

Rather change your code to use a server side click event OR change your server logic to return the data back to the AJAX function,loop through it and append it to the `GridView` using jQuery.Here's an example - [Binding GridView using AJAX](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/775585/Bind-Gridview-using-AJAX).

**Code behind:**

```
public class MyVideo
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public partial class Video : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            gvShow.DataSource = new List<MyVideo> { new MyVideo { ID = 0, Name = "Initial..." } };
            gvShow.DataBind();
        }
    }

    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static List<MyVideo> GetVideos(string videoid)
    {
        MyVideo v1 = new MyVideo { ID = 1, Name = "Video 1" };
        MyVideo v2 = new MyVideo { ID = 1, Name = "Video 2" };
        MyVideo v3 = new MyVideo { ID = 3, Name = "Video 3" };

        var videos = new List<MyVideo> { v1, v2, v3 };
        return videos.Where(v => v.ID == 1).ToList();//Hardcoding for simplicity
    }
}
```

**.ASPX:**

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#modal').click(function () {
                var id = $(this).attr('data-id');

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Video.aspx/GetVideos",
                    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                    data: '{videoid:"' + id + '"}',
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        var videos = data.d;
                        $("#gvShow").empty();

                        for (var i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {
                            var id = videos[i].ID;
                            var name = videos[i].Name;
                            var tr = "<tr><td>" + id + "</td><td>" + name + "</td></tr>"
                            $("#gvShow").append(tr);
                        }
                        $('#myModal').modal('show');
                    },
                    error: function (errordata) {
                        console.log(errordata);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <a href="#" id="modal" data-id="2">Click me</a>
        <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Videos</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <asp:GridView ID="gvShow" runat="server">
                        </asp:GridView>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

**Output:**

[image: Bind GridView using AJAX]

Answer (score 0):

In this javascript line

```
data: { "videoid": "id" },
```

you send the string `"id"`, not the number that contains the id.

So in this line

```
 gvShow.DataSource = VideoBL.GetVideo(query);
```

you probably call

```
 gvShow.DataSource = VideoBL.GetVideo("id");
```

or call it with empty string

```
 gvShow.DataSource = VideoBL.GetVideo("");
```

or I don't know what you actually send there, and there you get the error message.

Advice, debug your code line by line... and you find all that errors and how to correct them

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are trying to get data from request query string where your data is posted to the server as a form, you can try to get your posted data using

```
string query = Request["videoid"];
```

This will get data from the cookies, form, query string or server variables. or you can get your data from the posted form only using

```
string query = Request.Form["videoid"];
```