# How to get JSON data that is sent by AJAX in ASP C#?

Tags: c#, jquery, json

I am very new to these jquery,JSON,AJAX & asp C# so I really dont know the syntax to receive the JSON data that I sent from AJAX.

Heres my jquery

```
var name = $('#username').val();
var pass = $('#password').val();
var data = { name: $('#username').val(), pass: $('#password').val() };
var data2 = JSON.stringify(data)

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "auth.aspx",
    data: { "input": data2 },
    success: function (response) {
        alert(response);
    },
    failure: function (response) {
        alert("failed");
    }
});
```

and heres my C#

```
var name = Request.Form["input"];
```

I just want to send the data in JSON and read the JSON data in C# but somethings wrong and I cant read the JSON data

if I change the

```
data: { "input": data2 },
```

into

```
data: { "name": name, "pass": pass },
```

I can just read it by using

```
string name = Request.Form["name"];
string pass = Request.Form["pass"];
```

But Im guessing I cant use the same technique for JSON data?

Comment: Are you using webforms? If yes, you cannot use `Request.Form` to capture request through AJAX (only normal form submit), use webmethod to handle AJAX request.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please check the answer  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38280636/post-method-json-data-and-receive-in-aspx-file)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Post method json data and receive in aspx file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38280636/post-method-json-data-and-receive-in-aspx-file)